# Pass PDO prepared statement to variables

Tags: php, pdo

I am using a prepared statement to upload submitted information into a MYSQL database. I would like to know how to pass my prepared statements to a separate variable so I can post a summary of what was uploaded. Here is the following code:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO photos (Name, Type, Price, Description, Location,    status, id) 
VALUES (:item_name, :item_type, :item_price, :item_description, :image_location, :status, :id)");
$stmt->bindValue(':item_name', $_POST['item_name']);
$stmt->bindValue(':item_type', $_POST['item_type']);
$stmt->bindValue(':item_price', $_POST['item_price']);
$stmt->bindValue(':item_description', $_POST['item_description']);
$stmt->bindValue(':image_location', 'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
$stmt->bindValue(':status', 0);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', 0);

try{
    $stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e){
    $errors[] = $item_name . "not saved in database.";
    echo $e->getMessage();
```

I suppose my question is: How does PHP store the $stmt variable and then execute it? Is

```
$stmt->execute()
```

being treated as an array? If so how can I access each prepared value so I can post a summary of each value?

Thank you!

Comment: So, are you trying to see what is in things such as `$_POST['item_name']);`, or what the final statements looks like after "putting the variables in"?  The first is easy, the second impossible (without going into mysql and seeing which queries have been run against your database recently).

Comment: Yes, I'd like to see the specific instance of $_POST['item_name'] for each individual submission so I can echo out a summary of the information submitted. The only way I can see to do this is by created separate variables and extracting the $_POST['item_name'] again. I'd like to use what is stored in the $stmt variable already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `->bindParam()` you can pass the data only at the time of `->execute()`:

```
$data = [
  ':item_name' => $_POST['item_name'],
  ':item_type' => $_POST['item_type'],
  ':item_price' => $_POST['item_price'],
  ':item_description' => $_POST['item_description'],
  ':image_location' => 'images/'.$_FILES['file']['name'],
  ':status' => 0,
  ':id' => 0,
];

$stmt->execute($data);
```

In this way you would know exactly what values are going to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `$stmt->queryString` to obtain the SQL query used in the statement.
If you want to save the entire $stmt variable (I can't see why), you could just copy it. It is an instance of PDOStatement so there is apparently no advantage in storing it.